# Why I can't set and change my entire state with dispatcher like that?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, next.js

I have 2 questions on managing the state for my app.

**Part 1**: I can't update and set the entire state with my reducer, when I fetch the data from the server, but can change a part of that state:
`state.main_meals = action.payload` - works
`state = action.payload` - doesn't work

**Part 2**: I have heard that you shouldn't be using pure "setter" functions in redux, but how else am I supposed to set my state?

here is my reducer:

```
    setDiaryState: (state, action) => {
      state = action.payload;
    },
```

and my component:

```
  const diary = useAppSelector((state) => state.diary);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);

  useEffect(() => {
    {
      user &&
        db
          .collection("users")
          .doc(`${auth.currentUser?.uid}`)
          .collection("diaryState")
          .doc("currentState")
          .onSnapshot((doc) => {
            const data = doc.data();
            dispatch(setDiaryState(data));
          });
    }
  }, [user]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your reducer must always return a immutable state here,
 `state = action.payload;`
You are clearly mutating it which won't trigger a re-render,this can be fixed by simply add a return statement.

This would replace your entire state by action.payload.

```
 setDiaryState: (state, action) => {
  return {...action.payload};
},
```

if you wish to modify a subset of your state you can use:

```
setDiaryState: (state, action) => {
  return {...state, main_meals:action.payload};
},
```

This way you ensure that your state is always immutable.

Comment: Please mark this as accepted if I was able to solve your issue.

Comment: Note that "mutating" state _is_ okay, _if_ you are using our official Redux Toolkit package.  It uses Immer inside to allow "mutating" syntax which is turned into correct immutable updates.  See https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux#immutable-updates-with-immer and https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers .